# Android - RecyclerView don't scroll programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollto

I've got an activity which show up some data retrieved from a firebase. I have a method which do that programmatically scroll the recycler view to the today's event but if I need this method to work, I need to intent my activity two times... How can I fix it please?

Planning.java :

```
public void setUpRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

private void loadDataFromFirebase(){
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    if(eventsArrayList.size()>0){
        eventsArrayList.clear();}
    db.collection("Planning").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            for(DocumentSnapshot querySnapshot: task.getResult()){
                Events Nom = new Events(querySnapshot.getString("Nom"),querySnapshot.getString("Lieu"),querySnapshot.getString("Heure"),querySnapshot.getString("Minute"),querySnapshot.getString("Day"));
                eventsArrayList.add(Nom);
            }
            tvLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Planning.this, eventsArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            pos = MyRecyclerViewAdapter.getPos();
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Planning.this, "Erreur(s) :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("---]---", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    pos = MyRecyclerViewAdapter.getPos();
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);
}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter :

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewHolder> {

Planning planning;
ArrayList<Events> eventsArrayList;
static int pos;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Planning planning, ArrayList<Events> eventsArrayList) {
    this.planning = planning;
    this.eventsArrayList = eventsArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(planning.getBaseContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new MyRecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    holder.tvLieu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.tvNom.getLayoutParams();
    params.gravity = Gravity.START;
    holder.tvNom.setLayoutParams(params);
    holder.tvNom.setText(eventsArrayList.get(position).getNom());
    holder.tvLieu.setText(eventsArrayList.get(position).getLieu());
    holder.tvDate.setText(eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure() + "h" + eventsArrayList.get(position).getMinute());
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(eventsArrayList.get(position).getHeure())){
        holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvLieu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        holder.tvNom.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#227c97"));
    }
    if(TextUtils.equals(eventsArrayList.get(position).getDay(), String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))){
        pos = position;
    }
}

public static int getPos(){
    return pos;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventsArrayList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole adapter class and not just two methods?

Comment: I've just edited it

Comment: What does `MyRecyclerViewAdapter.getPos()` return and why do you use this position to scroll the recyclerview?

Comment: MyRecyclerViewAdapter.getPos() return the position of the item i want to scroll to, because this is the position of today's event